# Prevent draggable div from leaving container div while dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I have a draggable div with id mydiv nested in a container div with id container. when I drag the mydiv around I want it to stay inside and not leave the container div. How do I do that?

Here's the code:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the solution is to add few if statements in `elementDrag(e)` function but I don't know for sure. I want modifications in the existing code and not an entirely new solution. Please use only pure JavaScript.

Comment: This might help you https://codepen.io/Afirus/pen/rqXxQy

Comment: I want changes in the existing code, not a new solution!

Comment: If you don't want the `div` to  leave its container. The simplest thing to do would be to add the `eventListener` to the container, not the whole `document`. That way you don't have to write any extra code. Just `document.getElementById('container').onevent`

Comment: Can you do the changes in code and show me? I'm a noob

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it.

I got `#container` from the DOM and saved it into a variable,

I gave the container a `position: relative` declaration so the box would be positioned relative to the container

I changed all the `onevents` to native `addEventListeners` on the elements and I deleted all those variables `(pos1, pos2, pose3, pos4)` becauseI didn't use them anymore

The `mouseup` event is on the document and the `mousemove` is on the container to ensure the box doesn't leave it's container.

These calculations `(e.clientY - containerY)` and `(e.clientX - containerX)` get the absolute position of the mouse relative to the container. We got the `containerX` an d `containerY` from `getBoundingClientRect()` on the container element

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  const {
    x: containerX,
    y: containerY
  } = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").addEventListener('mousedown', dragMouseDown);
  else elmnt.addEventListener('mousedown', dragMouseDown);

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', closeDragElement);
    container.addEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    elmnt.style.top = (e.clientY - containerY) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (e.clientX - containerX) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', closeDragElement);
    container.removeEventListener('mousemove', elementDrag);
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative; /* This is very important */
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mydiv {
  width: 144px; /* This is very important */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The element isn't even draggable anymore?

Comment: My bad... The CSS comments were not closed correctly